# Connecting ALIX 6F2 through USB serial port, putty displays nothing

Tags: ubuntu, embedded, hardware, device, usbserial

Please help me connect ALIX with my laptop through a serial port to usb converter. Has anyone ever tried it? Do suggest if there is some different approach.

My OS: UBUNTU 12.04
Using Device : ALIX 6F2

I'm trying to connect ALIX to my PC using a Serial port to USB connection.
On doing '**dmesg**'  it detects the converter and shows following message:

> [  804.047907] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
>
> [  804.047917] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>
> [  804.047923] usb 2-2: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
>
> [  804.047928] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
>
> [  804.048499] pl2303 2-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
>
> [  804.049207] usb 2-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0

I even added the vendor Id and product id in my /etc/modules file and it looks like :

> lp
>
> vendor=0x067b product=0x2303

I configured putty over **/etc/ttyUSB0** with speed(baud) = 9600 as well as 115200.

But when I power up my ALIX board, nothing is displayed over putty.
I even tried with **minicom** and **gtkterm**

Please help me in this regard. Many thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: Sounds like you already got past this, but also make sure your user account is a member of a dialout group or whichever one owns the serial port devices on your system.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](http://www.pcengines.ch/pdf/alix2.pdf), the default speed is 38400 8N1, flow control = none.

> Getting started…
>
> - Install a bootable CF card. Hot swap of CF cards is not supported!
> - Connect serial port to a PC through null modem cable (RXD / TXD crossed over). Set terminal emulator to 38400 8N1, flow control = none or xon-xoff.
> - Connect Ethernet as needed.
> - Connect a 18V DC power supply to the DC jack. Power supply should be able to supply at least 12W for some margin. To avoid arcing, please plug in the DC jack first, then plug the adapter into mains.
>
> The board should now power on. All three LEDs will light during BIOS POST, then the system will try to boot, and turn off two of the LEDs. ALIX.6B2: one of the LEDs is driven by the miniPCI express card, normally not lit. You should see tinyBIOS startup messages, memory size, CF disk geometry on the serial console.

Comment: The board came with a 9V power supply adapter.
I've tried everything else but it's not working.
I'm using a serial cable and a serial to USB converter, not sure if the cable is null modem. In case anyone knows can tell how to verify a null modem cable.